# how to handle data contract serialize and application obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, obfuscation

i  have .net desktop application that uses datacontractserializer and it works fine but when i make release version and then obfuscate it the resulted saved xml is changed due to change of data members so how to fix that because it is essential to open release saved filed in debug version ?

saved file from debug verision

```
a:_activeFloor z:Id="5"><a:_Id>00e1a184-b7c5-43fb-a811-ce65cb3f4d65</a:_Id><a:_basePoint xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Elibre.Net.Core">
```

saved file from obfuscated verision

```
<a:Rvq8Prg9id z:Id="5" z:Size="0"/><a:T1d8Yh8Dsp z:Id="6">Default</a:T1d8Yh8Dsp><a:TLM8F3Im5Z z:Id="7">Default USA Imperial</a:TLM8F3Im5Z><a:_activeFloor z:Id="8"><a:GUc8GIYTTD>true</a:GUc8GIYTTD><a:_Id>d5e4915a-4e8e-4354-8e19-fe3f235697be</a:_Id><a:_basePoint xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Elibre.Net.Core">
```

and i am using net reactor with these settings
[image: .net reactor settings]

Comment: You need to either 1) Make sure obfuscation doesn't touch those classes, or 2) Make sure you annotate the classes and members with the right serialization attributes to override the naming algorithm.

Comment: If you're using the built-in XML serialization classes, then you can read [Controlling XML Serialization Using Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes).

Comment: i am using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-serializer

Comment: because it saves objects by reference and no duplication happens.

Comment: Then you need to apply the matching attributes to your types and members, such as `[DataMember(Name = "_activeFloor")]` on that property and so on. Basically you need to control serialization using attributes so that regardless of the obfuscated name of the type or the property, serialization still does the right thing.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes i guess you are right but that means i  have to spend lot of time in that but yes it will work . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decorate the affected classes/members with the System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute and .NET Reactor will automatically exclude the items from obfuscation. For example:

```
[System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute(ApplyToMembers = true)]
class myclass
{
  ...
}
```

or

```
class myclass
{
    [System.Reflection.ObfuscationAttribute()]
    internal string MyProp {get; set;}
}
```